# Unable to pack a NuGet package using dotnet CLI and nuspec file

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget-spec

I have several projects that I'm migrating from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET Standard 2.0. As a result, I'm trying to use the `dotnet pack` command to create my NuGet package while using my `nuspec` file with tokens. I have several custom build scripts that generate the version number for me. My generated files are not apart of version control but `nuspec` file is hence why I'd like to try and find a way to get the tokens to work, otherwise I'm stuck writing new scripts.

The first thing I did was to set the `GenerateAssemblyInfo` to false in the project files. In my most simplest project, the `csproj` file looks like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
     <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
     <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I then have an `AssemblyInfo.cs` that I generate as part of my build process. The file looks like this before I compile the project:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Company Name")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2019")]

#if DEBUG
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Debug")]
#else
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("Release")]
#endif

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("The Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("The Description")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("The Product")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("48d6ef54-a8fb-4876-8a9a-2fb8e8cd27e7")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.0.0.0")]
```

I then have a `.nuspec` file that I use to create my NuGet package which looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>My name</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>My Release Notes</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <projectUrl>http://url.local</projectUrl>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

After much reading (not a fan of who ever wrote the new docs for .NET Core) I believe this is the command I need to run in order to use my `nuspec` file:
`dotnet pack SubFolder\MyProject.Model.csproj /p:NuspecFile=MyProject.Model.nuspec /p:NuspecBasePath=nuget`

The result is this error:

> NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202,5): error : An error occured while
>   trying to parse the value '' of property 'version' in the manifest
>   file. [F:\Git\MyProject\Model\MyProject.Model\MyProject.Model.csproj]
>
> NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202,5): error :   Value cannot be null
>   or an empty string.
>   [F:\Git\MyProject\Model\MyProject.Model\MyProject.Model.csproj]
>
> NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202,5): error :   Parameter name: value
>   [F:\Git\MyProject\Model\MyProject.Model\MyProject.Model.csproj]

Based on the output, it's clear that the underlying targets file isn't grabbing the values out of my `AssemblyInfo.cs` but rather is trying to grab the values directly out of the `csproj` file instead. So I tried to simplify the process and ran this command: `dotnet pack MyProject.Model\MyProject.Model.csproj` which created my NuGet package, but did not have the metadata in my `nuspec` or in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.

I've read a lot of open issues on GitHub from both the `dotnet-cli` and `NuGet` projects that seem to be similar to what I'm experiencing, but none of them have given me a solution that works. Does anyone else think this is a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: You can generate NuGet packages from .Net standard libraries right from their properties -> package -> Generate NuGet package on build.

Comment: That won't integrate into my build process. I have custom scripts that generates the version for me and to a pattern that makes sense for my assemblies. Using the Visual Studio option won't work as my CI/CD process doesn't use VS and the version number generated by VS doesn't fit with my pattern.

Comment: Can you show an example nuspec file? I mean with $id$ filled in. I imagine version can't be parsed because it's not a dot net version and maybe there is an empty string in there somewhere.

Comment: I assure you that is not the problem. This process was working fine using .NET Framework 4.7 and using the `nuget` CLI. Only two things have since changed; the target framework is .NET Standard 2.0 and I'm using `dotnet` CLI to pack the project.

Comment: I understand, I can't reproduce. That's why I'm asking for a reproducable case.

Comment: So you created a a C# project with the project file, assembly info and the nuspec file I posted here and ran the pack command using the `dotnet` command and got a package with the correct metadata?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same problem and solved it by adding `<NuspecProperties>`to csproj as suggested here: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6636

```
<NuspecFile>package.nuspec</NuspecFile>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);configuration=$(Configuration)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);version=$(Version)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);id=$(PackageId)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);author=$(Authors)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);PackageProjectUrl=$(PackageProjectUrl)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);Description=$(Description)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);PackageReleaseNotes=$(PackageReleaseNotes)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);Copyright=$(Copyright)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);PackageTags=$(PackageTags)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);RepositoryType=$(RepositoryType)</NuspecProperties>
<NuspecProperties>$(NuspecProperties);RepositoryUrl=$(RepositoryUrl)</NuspecProperties>
```

Comment: In which node do you put these properties pls ?

Comment: @GGO - in PropertyGroup

Comment: and how you later use dotnet pack command @Miq ?

Comment: @frozzen10 just dotnet pack. I've been using Azure Pipelines, don't remember the plain cmd now. the code for the project where I used it is here: https://github.com/miqm/wpftoolkit/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml