# The required element 'metadata' is missing from the manifest error when doing dotnet pack

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to do create a nuget package by combining .nuspec and .csproj file.

My .csproj file looks like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>    
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Authors>Author name</Authors>
    <Company>Company name</Company>    

    <RepositoryUrl>RepositoryURL</RepositoryUrl>
    <VersionPrefix>0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
    <PackageId>SomeID</PackageId>
    <Description>Description</Description>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>    
    <NuspecFile>Projectname.nuspec</NuspecFile>     
  </PropertyGroup>
```

My .nuspec file looks like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>   
   <files>
      <file src=" somefile.json" target="lib" />    
    </files>
</package>
```

Now, when I try `dotnet pack` on .csproj file it fails with folllowing error:

`The required element 'metadata' is missing from the manifest.`

I have also tried couple of things here.

1. Tried to map properties explicitly as mentioned here:[Unable to pack a NuGet package using dotnet CLI and nuspec file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576651/unable-to-pack-a-nuget-package-using-dotnet-cli-and-nuspec-file) but it failed with the same errors
2. Tried to put explicit `metadata` tag into the .nuspec file.
   like `<metadata>$PackageId</metadata>` hoping that it will fetch `$package` from .csproj file but that fails with following error:

`The required element 'id' is missing from the manifest.`

How can I combine both .csproj and .nuspec to do `dotnet pack` without running into this errors? I am pretty sure it is possible just that I am missing something.

Any suggestions?

The required element 'id' is missing from the manifest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.nuspec has to have `meta-data` element. It would not build without it. While trying to combine .csproj and .nuspec make sure that the mandatory fields like

`<Authors>Author name</Authors>
 <Company>Company name</Company>

 <VersionPrefix>0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
 <PackageId>SomeID</PackageId>`

are always set in .nuspec. inside meta-data tag Not in .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

When using NuGet's MSBuild pack target (`dotnet pack` is an alias for `dotnet msbuild -t:pack`), you can't mix-and-match a nuspec file and csproj. If you provide your own nuspec file, it must be complete, but the NuGet team doesn't recommend this. It's better to pretend nuspec no longer exists and is just some historic artifact of old versions of NuGet.

(Almost) All metadata can be specified in the csproj with the [appropriate MSBuild property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target). MSBuild items of type `Content` automatically get put in the `content/` and `contentFiles/` folders. When you need to add additional files, you use the [`PackagePath` metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package).

On a side note, putting a config file in the `lib/` folder probably won't work as you want. Well, it might work when debugging .NET Core apps because assemblies are loaded from the global packages folder, where the packages are extracted. However, when publishing the app for deployment, the file won't be copied. But that's out of scope for this question.

Comment: While I agree with you comments, Consider a scenario where someone has written a code which relies on input.json file to be in the same directory where dll is living. In case of .Nuget package, that would be /lib folder. Now as you mentioned above .csproj forces all the content files to be copied in the /content or /contentfiles folder. If that is the case then the code should be reading input  from //content/input.json. Which is not ideal to read it one way when it is packaged and read it other way in development environment.